# ng-change is getting called when ng-model loads value from DB

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="dev in devs track by $index">
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <select class="form-control form-control-sm"
                    ng-change="Function1(null)"
                    ng-model="dev.name" ng-required="true">
                    <option ng-repeat="item in dev.resc"
                        value="{{item.Id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
                </select> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <input type="text" 
                    ng-change="Function2(some value)"
                    ng-model="dev.startDate">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <input type="text" my-date-picker
                    class="form-control form-control-sm" 
                    placeholder="Eg. 01/01/2018" ng-required="true"
                    ng-change="Function2(some value)"
                    ng-model="dev.endDate"
                    >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <input type="number"
                    class="form-control form-control-sm" 
                    placeholder="Eg. 100"
                    ng-change="Function3(some value)"
                    ng-model="dev.loc"
                    ng-required=true> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group input-group col-md-2">
                <input type="number" placeholder="Eg. 100"
                    class="form-control form-control-sm" 
                    ng-change="Function3(some value)"
                    ng-model="dev.Add"
                     ng-required="true"> 
        </div>
</div>
```

In above code when I iterate through devs **FUNCTION2** is getting called everytime `ng-model` loads value, but **FUNCTION1** and **FUNCTION3** are not getting called. **I do not want FUNCTION2 to get called**, how do I achieve this? what is wrong in above code? Hope my doubt is understandable.

Comment: are you making anychange to model in the `my-date-picker` directive?

Comment: Any value loads for 'dev.name' , 'dev.loc' and 'dev.Add'? Please provide some more details about the values loading in model. ng-change will call the function every time value gets change except the value is manipulated using javascript.

Comment: @Ved I am formatting Date format in `my-date-picker` directive

Comment: @ShaileshSaxena Yes values are getting loaded in dev.name' , 'dev.loc' and 'dev.Add' . Since function2 is getting called those values are changed in function which I do not want to change.

Comment: As you are formatting it will trigger `ng-change`

Comment: @Ved Thank you that explains issue

Comment: @Ved How to accept your answer?

Comment: Do you want me to add answer for same?

Comment: Yes that will close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are formatting the input model value in `my-date-picker` directive that triggers `ng-change` event. You need to handle it accordingly. Either use `$watch` or handle same inside directive itself.